# trouble running xmla script

Tags: ssis, ssas, ssms, data-warehouse, xmla

I am following a guide learning SSIS and i am running some xmla-script before the actual ssis-work begin.

the xmla-script runs against sample Analysis DB AdventureWorksDW2008R2.
The script:

```
<Batch xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
  <Parallel>
   <Process xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ddl2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2" xmlns:ddl2_2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2/2" xmlns:ddl100_100="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2008/engine/100/100" xmlns:ddl200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200" xmlns:ddl200_200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200/200">
    <Object>
      <DatabaseID>Adventure Works DW 2008R2</DatabaseID>
      <DimensionID>Dim Time</DimensionID>
    </Object>
    <Type>ProcessUpdate</Type>
    <WriteBackTableCreation>UseExisting</WriteBackTableCreation>
   </Process>
  </Parallel>
</Batch>
```

I get the output:

```
<return xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis">
  <results xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/xmla-multipleresults">
   <root xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:empty">
      <Exception xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:exception" />
      <Messages xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:exception">
       <Error ErrorCode="3239313431" Description="Errors in the metadata manager. The process type specified for the Date dimension is not valid since it is not processed." Source="Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Analysis Services" HelpFile="" />
      </Messages>
    </root>
  </results>
</return>
```

I am thinking this is trying to process the dimension time? There is no such dimension.
[image: dimensions inside adventureworks dw]

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ID of a dimension is not necessarily the same as the name.  Double click on your Date dimension and you will see the ID is Dim Time.

The error states that the Date dimension is not yet processed.  Can you browse the Dimension?  Try to right click -> process against the dimension and compare the scripts (script button at top of Process Dimension -Date window)